# $[0,1]$ without numbers which have the digit $8$ in them?

Tags: analysis, lebesgue-measure

I have an interesting task and I simply have no idea how to prove this.

Suppose we have the $[0,1]$ interval, but we remove all numbers, which contain the digit $8$. Prove, that the remaining set is a null set(Lebesgue measure=0).

Any ideas? Help is appreciated :)

Comment: Contradiction: there is no number containing the digit 8 if we convert the decimal expansions to binary :)

Comment: Then my task is false? I think not :D

Comment: Notice that the set $E_n$ of real numbers in $[0, 1]$ whose first $n$ digits of the decimal expansion contains no 8 satisfies $m(E_n) = (9/10)^n$.

Comment: $m$ means measure, and by that you mean that if $n$is big enough, then $(9/10)^n$ goes until 0?

Answer (score 3):

Try that (it's a bit rudimentary but it works):

- cut your interval in 10
- isolate the segment $[0.8,0.9[$, whose length is $0.1$ (and is obviously in the complementary of your set)
- for each of the other 9 sub-segments, the sub-sets with no 8 are similar, so you can focus on for instance $[0, 0.1[$
- but now your problem is just homothetic to the initial one
- you should get an equation satisfied by your measure $m$

Comment: Is this a similar construction to Cantor set? Can you go a bit forward after you delete $[0.8, 0.9[$? I really like your idea, but I have no idea how do you go forward.

Comment: There's indeed some sort of "auto-similarity" idea in my answer, but I'd rather not compare it with Cantor's idea :) How does Lebesgue measure of a set vary with an homothetic transformation?

Comment: It stays the same? :)

Comment: You mean that [0,1] without digit 8 is the same like [0, 0.1[ without digit 8?

Comment: It's "similar". Now go back to your course book ...

Comment: Hint (for the homothetic transf.): what are the measures of $(0,1)$ and $(0,10)$?